# dropdown menu hide behind div

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I dont know what should be a good title to my problem. Anyway I am a new learner and was testing to accomplish a drop down menu. http://jsfiddle.net/talk2rakesh143/gvRYY/3/

I tried to place the navMenu div inside header div in the center. I am trying to do a drop down menu of 6 items but the item 5 and 6 are hidden due to `overflow:hidden` property. If I remove the overflow property the div slides down. Please fix this case without sliding the header div down and explain me my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

#### Check this [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvRYY/4/)

Reduce your margin from 50px to set just 5px like following i do

#### CSS

```
#navMenu {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

and li height you can set 25px instead of 30px,

#### CSS

```
#navMenu ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Oh god!!! Thanks so much. you saved my day. I could not vote up as im new here. Well can you please let me know my mistake and explain your solution.

Comment: Wait... Though it served the purpose, but this was not what i wanted. It just moves the div little higher but it didnt make the menu bring to front. Please anybody bring the menu to the front irrespective of the navMenu div's position. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS just change the heights, put header height auto

```
#header {
    height: auto;
}
```

and nav menu height 500px or whatever suits you better

```
    #navMenu {
    height: 500px;
}
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e92Xx/)